# Is there a notion that quantify the dependence of a proof on AC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, proof-theory

The title is the question. I apologize if this is a naive question. I know there are weaker versions of AC,  but this is not what I am looking for. For example, is there a theorem that its proof invariantly requires **TWO** uses of AC? I don't know how to make it more precise. Thanks in advance.

Context: When proving "Sequentially compactness implies compactness", it looks like there are two instances of AC, for concreteness, let's say we adopt the "Lebesgue Number" approach. Then we need the following two lemmas:

> 1. Sequential compactness implies Lebesgue's Number Lemma.

which requires Axiom of Countable choice, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079513/avoiding-choice-in-proving-sequential-compactness-implies-lebesgue-number-lemma).

> 2. Sequentially compactness implies total boundedness of metric spaces.

which again uses ACC, see [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequentially_Compact_Metric_Space_is_Totally_Bounded).

It seems whatever approach we choose, there must be two instances of AC. So can we formalize this? Of course, given AC available, we can use it arbitrarily many times. But some mathematicians will intentionally reduce the use of it as much as possible. This leads me to question if there is a notion that quantifies the dependence of AC, or any axiom in general.

Comment: I think there is an effort to reduce the level of choice required, because that gives a stronger theorem.  The best is to use no choice at all, so it is a theorem of ZF.  Once you use a certain level of choice, you can use it as much as you want because it does not strengthen your assumptions to use it again.

Comment: Yes, but even given AC, they will try to reduce the uses as much as possible.

Comment: I think you may be over-generalizing. I bet there are mathematicians who do not make the slightest effort to avoid using the axiom of choice.

Comment: This is a great question! Not an answer, but: lower down in the hierarchy of theories, [**Weirauch reducibility** and its relatives can be used](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0157.pdf) to study the number of times a mathematical principle is invoked during a proof - roughly by casting everything in computational terms (so principles are replaced with algorithms). Some issues crop up in higher-level contexts (e.g. set theory), but you may still find the general idea interesting.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks for recognition! I never know there is a deep theory behind it. Could you point me to more references?

Comment: By fixing a choice function on a large enough set, you effectively reduce all your uses of choice into one. Because once you've fixed that choice function, the rest is given.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does minimizing use of the axiom of choice mean minimizing the number of times you mention the axiom, or minimizing the number of choices made? Could making all the choices at once result in your "large enough set" being a proper class?

Comment: @bof: Yes to both, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @bof Mary Ellen Rudin, a famous topologist, used to say that as a proof principle she had " well order everything in sight" (and some of her proofs are indeed heavy on that, including her classic proof that metric spaces are paracompact). She had no bones about using AC and transfinite recursion is quite powerful...

Comment: von Neumann-Bernays set theory assumes a chocie function for the universe of all sets, IIRC.